# How to change graph color instead of background color in matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, imshow

I want to add smoothing for graph, change color set and switch background color to white. But unfortunately all operation  which I try  change background interpolation and color, but not the graph. Where is a mistake in the code?

[image: Graph]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.interpolate
x = listx
y = listy
f = listf
xi, yi = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 5), np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), 5)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
rbf = scipy.interpolate.Rbf(x, y, f, function='linear')
zi = rbf(xi, yi)
plt.imshow(zi, cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('Blues'), interpolation='none', 
vmin=f.min(), vmax=f.max(), origin='lower', extent=[x.min(), x.max(), 
y.min(), y.max()])
plt.scatter(x, y, c=f)
plt.colorbar()
```

I expect to change color of graph from 'viridis' to 'Blues', but background color changed

Comment: Why don't you just use `plt.imshow(zi, cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('viridis'), ...]`? Also, Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: In your code you have exactly one plotting command, namely `plt.imshow`. However in the picture you show, at least two plotting commands need to have been called. What is that other plotting command? Why don't you change that other one, instead of plotting a new imshow?

Comment: It is my first question here
@Sheldore , yes, that's a good advise to read this information. I will run code before sending.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest You are right, now I added missed line and also understood what I need to change for getting expected result. Now I will look through methods for smoothing graph